# Convert JavaScript function to jQuery when using this.form

Tags: javascript, jquery, getelementbyid

I have multiple forms on one page which are similar to this:

```
<form action="hreftomyserver.php" method="get" target="_blank">
    <ul>
        <li id="li_address">8447 Pardee Hollow Rd.</li>
    </ul>
    <input class="btn" type="button" value="process form" onclick=myfunction(this.form) />
</form>
<form action="hreftomyserver.php" method="get" target="_blank">
    <ul>
        <li id="li_address">123 Main Street</li>
    </ul>
    <input class="btn" type="button" value="process form" onclick=myfunction(this.form) />
</form>
```

I'm using the following JavaScript to process the form on the `onclick` event:

```
function myfunction(form) {
    var address = form.getElementById('li_address').innerHTML;
    alert("the address is: " + address);
}
```

What I wish to do is access the `li_address` element with jQuery, but I don't know how to implement the equivalent jQuery to replace `form.getElementById('li_address').innerHTML`.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Comment: `address = $('#li_address').html()`

Comment: `$('#li_address').html()`. [More on jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: This will indeed retrun the li_address element, but keep in mind there are multiple forms on the page. This will return the first occurance of li_address in the first form. This is why this.form is used as reference to myfunction(form)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery remove the inline event handler, and use `text()` to get the elements text content :

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
    var adress = $('#li_address').text();
    alert("the address is: " + address);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use simple jQuery id selector

```
function myfunction(form){
  var address = $("#i_address").html();
  alert("the address is: " + address);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var address = form.getElementById('li_address').innerHTML;
```

Becomes:

```
var address = $('#li_address').html();
```

Since you're using IDs, there's also no need to get the form involved here. If you plan to have multiple address fields, consider using a class:

```
var address = $('.li_address').first().html();
```

Comment: But there are multiple forms

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax I was looking for:
$('#li_address', form).val()